# Imaginary number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello can someone help with this task, I think I came halfway but I don t understand how to get the complete answer.

So this task says if $\frac{x+2}{3+2i}-\frac{y+3}{3-2i}= 1$ than what equals $5x-y$?

I have simplified the equation and I got $3(x-y) - 2i(x+y)= 13$, I also tried adding to both side $2i(x+y)$ and then square it but it did not help.

Edit: after going through the same task i got correct simplification which is $3(x-y) - 2i(x+y) = 16 + 10i$ and correct result because of the explanation in the comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. From now on please use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936648/why-can-you-substitute-both-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-an-equation-separate

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your simplification is correct, all you have to do now is equate real and imaginary parts, so
$$
3(x-y) = 13
$$
and
$$
x+y = 0 .
$$

Now you have two equations in two unknowns to solve.

Comment: oh yes ! because the real part is equal to 13 and the imaginary part is equal to 0. 
Thank you!